# parse value from given string using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have this `string`:

```
String str = "Displaying bills 1 - 20 of 10000 in total";
```

And i want to parse the total value, `10000` in this case.
This is what i have try:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\\d+(?=\\s*in total)");
Match match = regex.Match("Displaying bills 1 - 20 of 10000 in total");
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

And currently this now succeed.

Comment: Don't delimit backslashes in verbatim strings.  So use `@"\d+(?=\s*in total)"` or `"\\d+(?=\\s*in total)"` (no `@`).

Comment: Yeah, the `@"\"` means 1 literal backslash and you have 2 before `d`, matching a ``\`` and a `d` in the text. When you remove `@` and make the string literal a regular one, the `"\\"` will get parsed exactly as 1 literal backslash that is necessary for the regex engine to parse `\d` as a digit shorthand character class.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in comment by @juharr, you just need to remove the double backslashes. The `@` at the beginning of the string marks it as a verbatim string, which doesn't require special characters to be escaped.

Comment: The only issue is the delimited backslashes since the OP only wants to match the number before "in total".  Your's will match the entire string instead.

Comment: You're correct. For some reason I thought he was getting the value from match.groups[1], which required the digits to be grouped. I'll edit.

Answer (score -1):

```
        string text = "Displaying bills 1 - 20 of 10000 in total";
        Regex r = new Regex(Regex.Escape("of") +"(.*?)"+Regex.Escape("in"));
        MatchCollection matches = r.Matches(text);
        MessageBox.Show(matches[0].Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: Why are you escaping string literals that don't contain anything that needs to be escaped in the first place?